# How to sort the closest beacon from onDistanceChanged method?

Tags: android, beacon, eddystone, google-nearby

I have this beacon application detecting the distance from the nearby beacons using nearby message API. Since distance keeps changing I am trying to find a way to get the closest beacon. I am new to android development. I would really be thankful if someone can help.

```
public void onDistanceChanged(final Message mNearbyMessagesList, final Distance distance) {
    EddystoneUid eddystoneUid = EddystoneUid.from(mNearbyMessagesList);
    Log.i(TAG, "Distance changed, message: " + eddystoneUid + ", new distance: " + distance);
}
```